# Execute SQL script stored in Azure Blob container via Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a SQL script stored in Azure Blob container as a ".sql" file. I want to execute/invoke this code using Azure Data factory. Please note that the script already has the SQL query I wish to execute and I simply intend to point to it and invoke it using ADF. How can we achieve this ?

Comment: do you want to execute the script in source query option?

Comment: @Leon Yue, if that means executing the script directly, then yes. I just don't want to copy and paste the content of the SQL script in the option of an activity and then execute. I wish to call the script directly.

Comment: Data Factory more focus on data transferring not executing the script directly. It can't achieve that for now. You need achieve that in code level and call the function in ADF.

Comment: @LeonYue, Thanks a lot. Looks like I will have to write a function for the same and execute the function using ADF. Thanks once again.

Comment: You're welcome! May I post it as answer? You can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Data Factory more focus on data transferring not executing the script directly. It can't achieve that for now. You need achieve that in code level and call the function in ADF.

Like you said, you will have to write a function for the same and execute the function using ADF.

Comment: Thanks for this response, I am looking for something similar that the OP describes. What do you mean specifically by "function"? Could you perhaps point to some documentation that is related to your answer? Thanks in advance!